# Number of combinations with restrictions for specific pairs

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem.
Assume that I have $20$ different variables, some pairs of which
are correlated. The aim is to calculate the number of
possible models with, for example, $5$ variables,
but the subsets must not have any of these correlated pairs.
So, firstly, all the possible combinations will be $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$
The variables which are correlated is known a priori (e.g. $6$ out of the $20$).
I suppose I must use the inclusion-exlusion principle.
Any idea?

Comment: Are the correlated pairs disjoint?

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: Then yes, inclusion-exclusion would be a useful approach. You can also think of your problem as counting independent sets in a graph where each node is a variable and each edge indicates that the pair of variables is correlated.

Comment: OK but can you elaborate more on that? Provide a formula etc?

Comment: What are your pairs?

Comment: Correlated variables. So, for example, from an initial set of 100 variables, i want to calculate the number of subsets containing 12 variables, but none of these subsets contain any of the correlated pairs (which are known a priori).

Comment: OK, the inclusion-exclusion approach starts with $\binom{100}{12}$ and subtracts $p \binom{100-2}{12-2}$, where $p$ is the number of correlated pairs.  The next term adds back $\binom{100-3}{12-3}$ or $\binom{100-4}{12-4}$ for each pair of correlated pairs, depending on whether that pair of pairs shares a variable or not.  Continue adding and subtracting terms for each $k$-subset of pairs, according to the parity of $k$.

Answer (score 4):

If there are $n$ pairs of correlated variables, one can choose a set of $K$ uncorrelated variables out of $N$ in the following way:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\text{min}(n,K)}\binom nk \binom {N-2n}{K-k}2^k,
$$
where $\binom nk$ stays for the number of ways to choose the $k$ correlated pairs out of $n$, $\binom {N-2n}{K-k}$ for the number of ways to choose the rest $K-k$ variables out of the uncorrelated ones, and $2^k$ -  for the number of ways to choose a set of correlated variables out of $k$ pairs.

Comment: Exactly this question I have addressed in my answer, which gives the number of all possible combinations with no two variables from the same correlated pair included.

Comment: $k$ is just a summation index which runs from $0$ to min($n,K$), in your example from $0$ to $6$.